# CSS only, is it possible to change each letter in a button to a different color at the same time on hover?

Tags: html, css

I should start by saying that I am still learning CSS. I don't know all that much about it, yet.

Currently this is what I have for the button:

```css
button {
  border: none;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com">
  <button>Google</button>
</a>
```

As you can see, the button is in a fixed position inside of an a tag so I can click on the entire box rather than just the text. I included the transition so the background would fade to white, but I removed the text color because I wanted to add specific colors to each letter rather than them all changing to the same color. For example, if I were to hover over the button, I want all of the colors to change to specific colors at the same time (it will be the Google colors).

The only way I know to change each individual color is to add a span tag to each of them with a different color and then add :hover, but then only that letter changes when I hover over it.

Is it possible to accomplish this with only CSS?

edit: if there is anything wrong with my code that is unnecessary please let me know. As I said, still learning.

Comment: No...not unless each letter is wrapped in it's own element.

Comment: ..also, buttons should not be inside links...just use one or the other....not both.

Comment: The easiest way is to encompass each letter inside an span. <span class="red">G <span>...

Comment: I would ditch the `<button>` tag as it's unnecessary.  You can apply all of those styles to the `<a>`.  As far as the color of each letter, wrap each in an element and use CSS for the rest.

Comment: use lettering.js .. it will add a <span>with a different classname around every character ( including white spaces ) and then you can use those classes to give them the color you want..check my answer for code example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You will need to give each letter a tag, and a special class. The special class will define the color.

```css
button {
  color: black;
}

button:hover .blue {
  color: blue;
}

button span {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

button:hover .red {
  color: red;
}

button:hover .yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

button:hover .green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="blue">G</span>
  <span class="red">o</span>
  <span class="yellow">o</span>
  <span class="blue">g</span>
  <span class="green">l</span>
  <span class="red">e</span>
</button>
```

Comment: What part of "only with CSS" did you miss?

Comment: As in the solution does not use JS? I couldn't find anywhere saying that the markup cannot be changed.

Comment: It's expressly stated in the question (penultimate paragraph) that he knows that wrapping each letter in a span is a way to do it but he doesn't want that solution.

Comment: No, he is mistaken by thinking that the `:hover` should go on the span element, while it actually should go on the `button` element. I edited my answer, check out the new snippet ;)

Comment: This is still not a CSS solution...it's an HTML solution. BUT in case he really wants this I'll go with it.

Comment: @JoeyZeolanceKnight If this answer works for you, feel free to accept it :)

Comment: @Narxx thank you for the help. I do see the errors in my code and way of thinking. I am still new to CSS and I now see that having a button inside an a tag is useless. Your code does work, but the only thing is that it does not transition to the colors. All of them change at once, but they do not fade. Do you know how to do this? Someone else answered using the :nth-child selector, but it only worked in jsfiddle. For whatever reason the exact same code did not work in Sublime Text 2.

Comment: @JoeyZeolanceKnight I have edited my snippet. Simply added `transition` to the span elements. That fixes all for you. Personally I think my code is more readable and elegant, but it's your choice on what to use. The answer is here for others to see as well :)

Comment: @Narxx thank you, very much. It looks perfect now. :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<a href='#'>
  <span class="blue">G</span>
  <span class="red">o</span>
  <span class="yellow">o</span>
  <span class="blue">g</span>
  <span class="green">l</span>
  <span class="red">e</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do the thing you want by CSS

The only thing that you can to make letters different is to use gradients

```
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

But I think that this is not what you want.

Another possible option is to create your own font, with each letter in one color.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically there is no reason to put a button inside a  but you can use the hover of the  to control elements inside it, like so:

### HTML

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div>
      <span>G</span>
      <span>o</span>
      <span>o</span>
      <span>g</span>
      <span>l</span>
      <span>e</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    border: none;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}
div:hover {
    background-color: white;
    span {
        transition: all ease 1s;
        &:first-child {
            color: #4285f4;
        }
        &:nth-child(2) {
            color: #ea4335;
        }
        &:nth-child(3) {
            color: #fbbc05;
        }
        &:nth-child(4) {
            color: #4285f4;
        }
        &:nth-child(5) {
            color: #34a853;
        }
        &:nth-child(6) {
            color: #ea4335;
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo** https://jsfiddle.net/yy0dyzdb/

Comment: Thank you, @user2728411, very much. I have removed the button from the a tag and your code works perfectly in jsfiddle, but when I copy/paste it over to Sublime Text 2 it doesn't work. It stills fades and all, but the colors won't change. Not sure why. For whatever reason, I don't think it's recognizing "&:first-child" for whatever reason.

Comment: @JoeyZeolanceKnight That's because he's using SASS, which will compile into CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this code example on how you may use lettering.js

```
<script src="_scripts/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {                  
                $(".kern").lettering();
            });
        </script>
    <style>
        .kern {
            font-size: 5em;
            font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .char2 {
            margin-left: -0.02em;
        }
        .char5 {
            margin-right: 0.1em;
        }
        .char7 {
            margin-left: -0.05em;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Working with lettering.js</h1>
        <p class="kern">Kern me!</p>
    </body>
```